# Feature Scaling, how to standardize

Tags: image, vector, normalization

Well I've an image and a vector, the vector consists 3 datas, positonX, positionY and Intensity(0-255). 
How do I standardize this, should standardization be done for each pixel or for an entire column, Also once standardized, for example I take the mean of 5 pixels, how do I get the original values(destandardize) back?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve and platform you are using in case you are using R you can try a package called imager. ..let me know if it helps

Comment: I'm  using openCV; I would like to standardize the feature space

Comment: Will it help if I do it in R or Python